# Apply CSS3 transition effects to Bootstrap elements

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I have a grid of elements arranged using Bootstrap ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/n2nd568o/)):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>1</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>2</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>3</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an onclick event that removes the clicked element:

```
$('.col-xs-3').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

This works fine. But the effect is quite jarring - see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2nd568o/). I want to apply a CSS3 transition effect to each `col-xs-3` so when one is removed, the remaining elements use a transition to move and fill the space of the deleted element rather than just jumping.

I have added the following css which has no effect:

```
.col-xs-3{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: A CSS transition occurs between 2 states of an element, but here you're simply removing it from the DOM. Even if something was to occur in 1s, you wouldn't know about it - because you've removed it.

Comment: Instead of `$(this).remove();`, try this: `$(this).css({opacity: 0, width: 0});`. It's certainly no finished product, but it'll give you an idea about the whole 'states' thing I mentioned. It now has `opacity` and `width` to work with.

Comment: Thanks @JayMee. Good point. But I am not concerned with the element I have removed. But the space it leaves behind. The other elements move to fill this space. So I need the transition applied to the remaining elements - hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's because the bootstrap classes add padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JayMee is right, the proper way to handle this is transitioning properties in the removed element. This will make the remaining elements change position smoothly.
We can make the element disappear instantly (not setting a transition on opacity) and then reduce the width

```js
jQuery(function(){
 $('.col-xs-3').click(function(){
     $(this).css({"opacity": "0", "width": "0px", "padding": "0px"});
    });
});
```

```css
.col-xs-3{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.content-block{
    width:90%;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px auto;
    background:pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>1</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>2</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>3</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>4</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>5</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>6</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>7</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>8</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>9</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>10</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>11</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content-block"><p>12</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```